# Get Sum of Count

Tags: sql-server

The View obtains the first three columns. I need to add one more column (`totalCount`) to the view that obtains the total count:

```
CId CCId CCount  totalCount
1      a      3         6
1      a      3         6
1      b      3         6
1      c      3         6
2      b      2         6
2      b      2         6
2      a      2         6
2      a      2         6
3      v      1         6
```

How to get the `totalCount` as 6?

(Business rule for Cid=1  Ccount=3 Cid=2 Ccount=2  Cid=3 Ccount=1 So the totalCount =3+2+1 =6)

Comment: Is the total count the number of unique CId/CCId combinations?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.CID, a.CCID, a.CCOUNT,
        b.TotalCount
FROM    Table1 a, (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT cCOunt) TotalCount 
                   FROM Table1) b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67bc9/3)

**UPDATE**

As Andomar pointed out on the comment, An update has been made on the query,

```
SELECT  a.CID, a.CCID, a.CCOUNT,
        b.TotalCount
FROM    Table1 a, 
(
  SELECT SUM(TotalCount) TotalCount
  FROM
  (
      SELECT MAX(cCOunt) TotalCount 
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY CId
   ) c
) b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32165/6)

Comment: That would fail if two Cid's had the same CCount.  For example, if you added `Cid=4 Ccount=1` to the example rowset.

Answer (score 1):

With this code I came to the desired result:

```
select CId
      ,CCId
      ,CCount
      ,(select SUM(a.tcount) 
          from (select distinct CId ,CCount as tcount
       from  dbo.Test) as a ) totalcount
from dbo.Test
```

Comment: I've added some formatting to your answer to make it more readable. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to see what kind of formatting you can add.

Answer (score 0):

From your example data, I'm assuming a `Cid` can only have one, possibly repeated, value of `CCount`.  In that case you can pick a random one (say `max`) using a `group by`, and `sum` those:

```
select  sum(OneCCCount) as TotalCount
from    (
        select  max(CCount) as OneCCCount
        from    YourTable
        group by
                CId
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```